# Adding new nodes, nodetool rebuild returns "Unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range"

Tags: cassandra

I have the cassandra 4.0.1 cluster with 3 nodes (datacenter1) and we have decided that we need to add the second datacenter (datacenter2), I have done all the steps described in [this article](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html)

[image: cassandra nodetool status]

First of all, we have added the nodes one by one with the `auto_bootstrap: false` option in the `cassandra.yaml` configuration for all three new nodes.

The replication factor was `rf=o` for datacenter2 during adding/bootstraping process.
Then we have changed from `rf=0` to `rf=3` for system_auth, system_traces, system_distributed keyspaces and my user keyspace which is named big_data for datacenter2 through `ALTER KEYSPACE`.

All the nodes have joined to cluster successfully, but there is one strange situation there:

We cannot do the rebuild process from datacenter1 and cassandra tells me the following:

```
nodetool: Unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range Full(/192.168.1.141:7000,(9143760283360780305,-9086318401025854203]) in keyspace system_auth
```

...and I saw the same print on the next new nodes. What can I do with it?

Schema version is the same on all nodes.
If I perform **full repair** all the data will appear on all new nodes, but the rebuild process still doesn't work properly in this case.

I need your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good chance that you missed a step when adding the new DC.

The high level steps are:

1. Switch `system_distributed`, `system_auth`, `system_traces` and application keyspaces to `NetworkTopologyStrategy` with replicas only in the existing DC.
2. Repair the keyspaces.
3. Add nodes to the new DC with `auto_bootstrap: false`.
4. After all new nodes are running, alter the keyspaces to add replicas in the new DC.
5. Build the nodes in the new DC with:

```
$ nodetool rebuild -- source_dc
```

If you performed step (4) without having done steps (1) and (2) then you'll run into the problem you reported above.

Just go back, re-do the steps again and you should be fine. Cheers!

Comment: It's works now! thanks a lot! it's fantastic, this time i have done all these steps without altering with "rf=0' from that article in datastax.

Comment: Please start a new post. I hope you understand that if we keep responding to follow up questions, the comments section will be a never-ending thread. Cheers!

Comment: ok, i will.....